# Convert String to smalldatetime object using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to use SSIS to import a CSV to a Database. I am having issues with a Column that is a `smalldatetime`datatype that does not have null values . The string associated with this column is formatted `MMddYYYY` that has no null values either.
Currently I am trying to use a Derived column to convert the string to `DT_DBTIMESTAMP`.

Currently I am getting the error message: `[Derived Column [36]] Error: An error occurred while attempting to perform a type cast.`

In my expression Field I have: `(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING([Derived Column 5],5,4) + "/" + SUBSTRING([Derived Column 5],1,2) + "/" + SUBSTRING([Derived Column 5],3,2))`

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: seems data related. Ensure that the input data format is actually MMddYYYY in all cases and to be on the safe side, trim the column in your expression: (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING(trim([Derived Column 5]),5,4) + "/" + SUBSTRING(trim([Derived Column 5]),1,2) + "/" + SUBSTRING(trim([Derived Column 5]),3,2)). Also make sure that you don't have empty or null values in this columns.

Comment: This link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036(v=sql.105).aspx says the format required for `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fff]`. Why are you using slashes in your conversion? Also try tacking 00:00:00 on to the end to satisfy the hh:mm:ss part. Also ensure you are inspecting your file in notepad, not Excel. Lastly load your Column 5 into a varchar field first and inspect it there before converting.

Comment: Unfortunately @ElectricLlama that didn't work

Comment: Didn't work? What happened when you loaded the data in as a varchar? Surely that worked. Are you observing the data in Excel or CSV?

Comment: My data is clean I've inspected it manually and through a couple of automated tools I have. I ended up having to use scripting and also changing the DB data type to DATETIME instead of SMALLDATETIME for some reason it just would not work. but thank you for all your help I've got my requirements finished now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started in IT over 25 years ago, and find it somewhat depressing that we are **still** struggling to get dates from two different systems to integrate ... sigh ...

I would abandon SSIS expressions for this requirement and use a Script Task instead.  The .NET DateTime.TryParse method is an elegant solution that can easily be extended for varying date formats.

Comment: I feel your pain but I put it down to 50% inexperience and 50% blatant driver bugs.

Comment: @ElectricLlama I guess my point was that we shouldn't need years of experience to figure out how do something as fundamental as integrate dates.

Comment: I totally agree, you'd think it would be easier by now. At least there is an ISO standard format now (maybe there has been for a long time but I've only become aware of it in the last few years).